# How to reduce RAM consumption of gensim fasttext model through training parameters?

Tags: python, gensim, fasttext

What [parameters](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_fasttext.html#training-hyperparameters) when training a gensim fasttext model have the biggest effect on the resulting models' size in memory?

gojomos answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407649/fasttext-bin-file-cannot-fit-in-memory-even-though-i-have-enough-ram) mentions ways to reduce a model's size during training, apart from reducing embedding dimensionality.

There seem a few parameters that might have an effect: thresholds for including words in the vocabulary especially. Do the other parameters also influence model size, for example ngram range, and which parameters have the largest effect?

I hope this is not too lazy of a question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main parameters affecting `FastText` model size are:

- `vector_size` (dimensionality) - the size of the model is overwhelmingly a series of vectors (both whole-word and n-gram) of this length. Thus, reducing `vector_size` has a direct, large effect on total model size.
- `min_count` and/or `max_final_vocab` - by affecting how many whole words are considered 'known' (in-vocabulary) for the model, these directly influence how many bulk vectors are in the model. Especially if you have large enough training data that model size is an issue – & are using `FastText` – you should be considering *higher* values than the default `min_count=5`. Very-rare words with just a handful of usage examples typically *don't* learn good generalizable representations in word2vec-like models. (Good vectors come from many subtly-contrasting usage examples.) But because by Zipfian distributions, there are typically a lot of such words in natural language data, they *do* wind up taking a lot of the training time, & tug *against* other words' training, & push more-frequent words out of each-other's context windows. Hence this is a case where, counter to many peoples' intuition, throwing away some data (the rarest words) can often *improve* the final model.
- `bucket` – which specifies exactly how may n-gram vectors will be learned by the model, because they all share a collision-oblivious hashmap. That is, no matter how many unique n-grams there really are in the training data, they'll all be forced into exactly this many vectors. (Essentially, rarer n-grams will often collide with more-frequent ones, and be just background noise.)

Notably, because of the collisions tolerated by the `bucket`-sized hashmap, the parameters `min_n` & `max_n` actually *don't* affect the model size at all. Whether they allow for lots of n-grams of many sizes, or much fewer of a single/smaller range of sizes, they'll be shoehorned into the same number of `bucket`s. (If more n-grams are used, a larger `bucket` value may help reduce collisions, and with more n-grams, training time will be longer. But the model will only grow with a larger `bucket`, not different `min_n` & `max_n` values.)

You can get a sense of a model's RAM size by using `.save()` to save it to disk - the size of the multiple related files created (without compression) will roughly be of a similar magnitude as the RAM needed by the model. So, you can improve your intuition for how varying parameters changes the model size, by running varied-parameter experiments with smaller models, and watching their different `.save()`-sizes. (Note that you don't actually have to `.train()` these models - they'll take up their full allocated size once the `.build_vocab()` step has completed.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer! :D